# Syntax for if/else condition in SCSS mixins

Tags: css, if-statement, sass, mixins

I created a SASS `@mixin` which contains `@if` conditions to assign styling to elements based on their `z-index` property to create some sort of elevation.

However what ever I am trying it will not work out.

I'm pretty sure I am doing something just slightly wrong that affects everything else.

I'd appreciate your feedback. Thanks in advance!

```
    $background: #121212;
    $surface: #1f1f1f;
    $surface-shade_1: #282828;
    $surface-shade_2: #303030;
    %surface {
      background-color: $surface;
    }

    %surface-shade_1 {
      background-color: $surface-shade_1;
    }

    %surface-shade_2 {
      background-color: $surface-shade_2;
    }

    @mixin elevation($elevationValue) {
      @if $elevationValue>0 {
        @extend %surface;
      }
      @else if $elevationValue>4 or $elevationValue=4 {
        @extend %surface-shade_1;
      }
      @else if $elevationValue>8 or $elevationValue=8 {
        @extend %surface-shade_2;
      }
      z-index: $elevationValue * 50;
    }

    nav {
      @mixin elevation(4);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use **@mixin** inside the CSS files you can use like `@include mixin-name` and also use directly `$elevationValue >= 4` instead of `$elevationValue>4 or $elevationValue=4` it becomes much cleaner.

```
$background: #121212;
$surface: #1f1f1f;
$surface-shade_1: #282828;
$surface-shade_2: #303030;
%surface {
  background-color: $surface;
}

%surface-shade_1 {
  background-color: $surface-shade_1;
}

%surface-shade_2 {
  background-color: $surface-shade_2;
}

@mixin elevation($elevationValue) {
  @if $elevationValue > 0 {
    @extend %surface;
  }
  @else if $elevationValue >= 4 {
    @extend %surface-shade_1;
  }
  @else if $elevationValue >= 8 {
    @extend %surface-shade_2;
  }
  z-index: $elevationValue * 50;
}

nav {
  @include elevation(4);
}
```